# Trying to find datediff when trying to concat text field SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following piece of code that I thought would work when trying to find the  `datediff` but I have a feeling it doesn't work due to the concatenating I am doing to the year before `try_parse`. I cant simply put `april-1993` because I can't change the data that was given. I need to somehow find a way to find the date difference for `apr-93` (in this format).

```sql
select
  try_cast(
    datediff(
      year,
      try_cast(
        left(
          'apr-93',
          len('apr-93') - 2
        ) + '19',
        2)
        as date
      ),
      try_cast('2012-01-01' as date)
    )
  as varchar)
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 11.0.7507.2
and at the end, I'm just trying to find the difference in years between apr-1993 and 2012-01-01 which should just be 19.

Comment: `as varchar` when using a varchar **always** specify the length.

Comment: Also you appear to have misplaced a parenthesis. Do you want the number of year boundaries crossed (that is what you would get currently) or do you want the number of days / 365? And have you considered `try_convert(date, left('apr-93', 3) + ' 01 19' + right('apr-93', 2), 100)`

Comment: SQL Server with a version number of 11.0.7507.2 is SQL Server **2012** - not 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following:

Complete the date of 'apr-93' by adding the day part to it:

```
CONCAT('01-', 'apr-93')
```

Then use the `DATEDIFF` on that complete date:

```
Select DATEDIFF(
                 YEAR, 
                 TRY_CAST(CONCAT('01-', 'apr-93') AS DATE), 
                 TRY_CAST('2012-01-01' as DATE)
               ) AS DF
```

The output is 19.

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5UiIP-C6).

Note that years from 50-99 will be considered in 20th century i.e. 19xx and years from 0-49 will be considered in 21th century i.e. 20xx.

If you want to consider all dates with 'MMM-yy' format as 19xx you may try the following:

```
Select DATEDIFF(
                 YEAR, 
                 TRY_CAST(CONCAT('01-', REPLACE('apr-93', '-', '-19')) AS DATE), 
                 TRY_CAST('2012-01-01' as DATE)
               ) AS DF
```